# apply mask to html element cross-browser

Tags: css, html, mask

I'm trying to obtain the application of a mask on html elements compatible with all browsers. At the moment only it works on Firefox. What's wrong?

```
<svg class="svg-defs" width="10" height="10" baseProfile="full" version="1.2">
   <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
         <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></circle>
      </mask>
   </defs>
</svg>

<div></div>

div {
    -webkit-mask:url(#mask);
    -moz-mask:url(#mask);
    -o-mask:url(#mask);
    -ms-mask:url(#mask);
    mask:url(#mask);

    height:200px;
    width:200px; 
    background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phanorat/u1gc89y6/3/

Comment: What browsers you tried? `mask` has limited support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Comment: in chrome it should work.. but it doesnt